# Reassign the starting Julian date (July 1st = Julian date 1, southern hemisphere)

Tags: r, date, julian-date, chron

My data set includes various observations at different stages throughout the year.

- `year` when samples were collected.
- `site` location of measurement
- `Class` physical stage during r of measurement
- `date` date of measurement
- `Julian` Julian date

The final measurements usually occur in the early part of the new year, which is the summer time in the southern hemisphere. (e.g. summer is winter, spring is fall).

`year site   Class       date Julian
1  2009  10C   Early 2008-09-15    259
2  2009  10C      L2 2008-09-29    273
3  2009  10C      L3 2008-12-15    350
4  2010  10C   Early 2009-08-31    243
5  2010  10C      L2 2009-09-14    257
6  2010  10C      L3 2009-12-11    345
7  2012  10C   Early 2011-08-23    235
8  2012  10C      L2 2011-09-22    265
9  2012  10C      L3 2011-12-03    337
10 2012  10C LSample 2012-03-26     86
11 2013  10C   Early 2012-09-07    251
12 2013  10C      L2 2012-09-30    274
13 2013  10C      L3 2012-12-17    352
14 2014  10C   Early 2013-09-02    245
15 2014  10C      L2 2013-09-16    259
16 2014  10C      L3 2013-12-16    350
17 2014  10C    LMid 2014-01-07      7
18 2015  10C   Early 2014-09-08    251
19 2015  10C      L2 2014-09-30    273
20 2015  10C      L3 2014-12-01    335`

I am having a difficult time converting/reassigning the Julian start date to July 1st instead of January 1st. The dot plot below illustrates the final sampling that occurs at the beginning of the year (February-March).
[image: Example plot of data]
The `chron` package has an option to reorder the `origin` but I cannot get it to work properly with my data.

`library(chron)
library(dplyr)
data.date <- data %>%
  mutate(July.Julian = chron(date,format = c(dates = "ymd"), options(chron.origin = c(month=7, day=1, year=2008))))
Error in chron(c("2008-09-15", "2008-09-29", "2008-12-15", "2009-08-31",  : 
  misspecified chron format(s) length`

or

`July.Julian = chron(data$date, format = c(dates = "ymd"), options(chron.origin = c(month=7, day=1, year=2008)))
Error in chron(c("2008-09-15", "2008-09-29", "2008-12-15", "2009-08-31",  : 
  misspecified chron format(s) length`

I am trying to start the Julian date as 1 instead of 182.

Thoughts or suggestions are welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that `July.Julian` is supposed to be `Julian` days past July 1st:

```
transform(date.data, July.Julian = as.chron(sprintf("%d-07-01", year)) + Julian)
```

or

```
date.data %>% mutate(July.Julian = as.chron(sprintf("%d-07-01", year)) + Julian)
```

Note that one does not actually need chron here.  Just replace `as.chron` with `as.Date` and either of these work.

Comment: This gives an error, maybe because of the year-month-day format of my dates?: `Error in sprintf("%d-07-01", c("2008-09-15", "2008-09-29", "2008-12-15",  : 
  invalid format '%d'; use format %s for character objects` . When I try it with `%s` I get really weird dates: `2009  10C   Early 2008-09-15    259    11/30/47
2  2009  10C      L2 2008-09-29    273    12/28/47
3  2009  10C      L3 2008-12-15    350    05/30/48`

Comment: `date` should have been `year` in both cases. Its fixed now.

Comment: Many thanks! Converting the `July.Julian` date column into an offset Julian seems to reassign my dates correctly (the plots look good too).  `year date Julian July.Julian Julian2
2009 2008-09-15    259  2010-03-17      76`